# Java collection datastructure with last modified time

Tags: java, data-structures, collections, guava, apache-commons

Do we have a java collection library which returns the lastmodified/inserted date for an object added to a collection.

e.g.

```
TimeBasedSet<Foo> foos = new TimeBasedSet<>();
foos.add(foo1); //executed at t1
foos.add(foo2); //executed at t2
foos.add(foo1); //executed at t3

foos.lastModifiedDate(foo1); //returns t3
foos.lastModifiedDate(foo2); //returns t2
foos.insertedDate(foo1); //returns t1
foos.insertedDate(foo2); //returns t2
```

Comment: never saw anything like this, but it's not hard to implement your own, extending an existing implementation and overriding the methods that modify the Set

Answer (score 4):

I'm not aware of any existing implementation.

To implement your own, just create a new class that implements the set interface.

```
public class TimeBasedSet implements Set<E> { ... }
```

You can create a nested class (non-static) within that class for the value element type like this:

```
private class Val {
    public E element;  //public out of laziness since its nested/private.
    public Date creationDate;
    public Date lastModifiedDate;
}
```

The value element can store the value type you're literally trying to store (whatever the E is in your map interface implementation) along with the metadata for time.

Then when you override add/get you call the set add/get and store the new time right after that.

After that, you just need a couple functions to lookup the times.

Answer (score 1):

It's already mentioned, that there's no such data structure among existing collections.

As an alternative solution I can offer you a simple wrapper over `HashMap`:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

class TimeBasedSet<T> {

    private static class StorageData {

        StorageData(Date insertionDate, Date lastModificationDate) {
            this.insertionDate = insertionDate;
            this.lastModificationDate = lastModificationDate;
        }

        Date insertionDate;
        Date lastModificationDate;
    }

    private Map<T, StorageData> storage = new HashMap<>();

    public void add(T key) {
        Date date = new Date();

        StorageData storageData = new StorageData(storage.containsKey(key) ? storage.get(key).insertionDate : date, date);

        storage.put(key, storageData);
    }

    public Date getInsertionTime(Object key) {
        return storage.containsKey(key) ? storage.get(key).insertionDate : null;
    }

    public Date getLastModificationTime(Object key) {
        return storage.containsKey(key) ? storage.get(key).lastModificationDate : null;
    }
}
```

Implementation that's shown above is rather simple. We store all data in `HashMap`, where key is some parametrized type `T` and value is a `StorageData` class containing insertion time and last modification time of the stored key.

In `add` method we create `StorageData` for the added key. Last modification time is always set to the current time. Insertion time is also set to the current time, but if this key is already in `Map` we process insertion time appropriately. Then we put new *key-value* pair into the `Map`.

Also two getters're added for each type of date.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you "John Humphreys - w00te" and "Edgar Rokyan".

I analyzed both approaches and combined your suggestions to implement the TimeBasedSet.

1. TimeBasedSet should implement Set, since I need to use other Set methods e.g. containsAll, addAll etc.
2. Wrapping E within another object Val complicates the implementation. e.g. containsAll method requires unwrapping Val.

Implementation details,

1. Maintain an internal Set internalSet and Map storageDataMap.
2. Delegate the calls from TimeBasedSet size, isEmpty, contains etc methods to internalSet.
3. For add, addAll, remove, removeAll, retainAll and clear methods update storageDataMap and then delegate calls to internalSet.